# Find $\bigcap_{k\in\mathbb{Z^+}} B_k$ where $B_k=\left[3/k,\left(5k+2\right)/k\right)\cup\left\{10+k\right\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The question was originally, instead of $\bigcap_{k\in\mathbb{Z^+}}B_k$, to find $\bigcap_{k\in\mathbb{N}}B_k$, but this did not make any sense. For instance, consider the interval I am finding the intersection of:
\begin{align}
\bigcap_{k\in\mathbb{N}}B_k=\bigcap_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\left[\frac{3}{k},\frac{5k+2}{k}\right)\cup\left\{10+k\right\}.\tag{1}
\end{align}
A $k=0$ would be undefined, wouldn't it? So I believe the first index won't work, but then am I allowed to change the index in this way? So instead I think I would have
\begin{align}
\bigcap_{k\in\mathbb{Z^+}}B_k=\left[3,5\right).\tag{2}
\end{align}
But is this right?

Thank you for your time,

Comment: Some people say that $0 \notin \Bbb N$, so it probably made sense. Also, isn't $5 \in B_k$ for every $k$? Why are you excluding it in the answer?

Comment: @Arthur Really!? I've always thought that $0\in\mathbb{N}$ but then $0\not\in\mathbb{Z^+}$, so it simply made sense to change it. I just checked earlier in the book and it turns out that they explicitly state $0\not\in\mathbb{N}$. So I apologize for posing the question, I do not know why I didn't reference that first. Why don't we just call that set $\mathbb{Z}^+$ then instead of $\mathbb{N}$?? That doesn't make any sense. It's annoying to declare $\mathbb{Z^+}\cap \left\{0\right\}$ or $\mathbb{N}\cap \left\{0\right\}$.

Comment: Well, if $0 \in \Bbb N$, then it wouldn't make sense as it was written, no. That's probably just a slip-up from the author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to show that $[3,5]\subset \bigcap_{z\in\mathbb{N}}B_k.$ So, it only remains to shou that $ \bigcap_{z\in\mathbb{N}}B_k\subset[3,5].$ If $x<3$ then $x\notin B_1.$ That is, $ \bigcap_{z\in\mathbb{N}}B_k\subset[3,+\infty).$ If $x>5$ then there exists $K\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$\frac{5K+2}{K}<x.$$ Thus,

$$k\ge K\implies x\notin B_k\cap B_{k+1}.$$ So, we have shown that

$$[3,5]\subset \bigcap_{z\in\mathbb{N}}B_k.$$

Note that I am considering $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,\cdots, \}.$ It can exist some ambiguity because one can assume $0\in\mathbb{N}$ or not. But, in the context of this particular problem, if $0$ is a natural number then $B_0$ makes no sense, as you have said.

Comment: You're welcome.